# Is it possible to use Qt's built-in libpng library directly?

Tags: qt, libpng

I'm saving a QImage to a PNG file and QPNGHandler isn't customizable enough (I need png_set_filter) so I need to write my own PNG handler.  If Qt was configured without -system-libpng, is it possible for me to directly access Qt's bundled version?

Right now I'm statically compiling Qt, but that could change.

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfactory solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Instead I just use the system libpng and pull in its header files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I suppose it should be possible. I see the symbols are inside libQtGui.so:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm libQtGui.so.4.7.2 | grep png_create_read_struct
0027b7c0 T png_create_read_struct
0027b3b4 T png_create_read_struct_2
```

I see it includes all the sources inside libQtGui.so from src/gui/image/qpnghandler.pri unless system-png is specified in configure. I guess you'll have to manually get the headers ad specify in your .pro file cause I don't think Qt is exporting those when installing.

Comment: How do you manually get the headers out of a pre-built Qt installation, won't they move depending on the platform?